# TypeScript type annotation to express variable numbers of generics?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've been converting a project of mine from JavaScript to TypeScript,
but this type annotation has me stumped.
I have a `Serializer` interface and a class for combining these interfaces like the following:

```
interface Serializer<T> {
    serialize(value: T): ArrayBuffer
}

class UnionSerializer {
    constructor(types) {
        this.types = types
    }
    serialize(value) {
        for (const type of this.types) {
            try {
                return type.serialize(value) //throws error if type can't serialize value
            }
            catch (e) {}
        }
        throw new Error('No type matched')
    }
}
```

How would I go about writing a type declaration for `UnionSerializer` based on `Serializer`?
Clearly its type depends on the `types` array passed into it. So it has an interface like:

```
interface UnionSerializerConstructor {
    new <T1>([t1]: [Serializer<T1>]): Serializer<T1>
    new <T1, T2>([t1, t2]: [Serializer<T1>, Serializer<T2>]): Serializer<T1 | T2>
    //...
}
```

What is the most elegant way to write type annotations for the `UnionSerializer` class, ideally without writing out all of the constructor annotations for different lengths of the `types` array?

Comment: Is `Serializable<>` just a typo for `Serializer<>`?  Or is it a separate type you haven't defined here?

Comment: Yeah, typo, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a difference between the type of `new UnionSerializer([a,b])` and the type of `new UnionSerializer([b,a])`?  It doesn't really look like it, given that your type signatures for `UnionSerializerConstructor` return a `Serializer<A | B>` which would be the same as `Serializer<B | A>`.  In that case, good news!  You don't need to worry about specifying an generic arbitrary-length tuple type, which you [can't do yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5453).  Instead, just accept an array:

```
interface UnionSerializerConstructor {
    new <T>(types: T[]): Serializer<T>
}
```

If you pass in `[a,b]` (where `a` is an `A` and `b` is a `B`) to the constructor, it will infer `A | B` for `T`, as you want.

---

Now, it looks like you expect the values passed into the constructor to *themselves* be `Serializer` instances.  In that case, you should probably do this instead:

```
interface UnionSerializerConstructor {
    new <T>(types: (Serializer<T>)[]): Serializer<T>
}
```

I might as well go ahead and type your `UnionSerializer` for you:

```
class UnionSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {
  constructor(public types: (Serializer<T>)[]) {
    // next line is unnecessary with "public types" above
    // this.types = types
  }
  serialize(value: T): ArrayBuffer {
    for (const type of this.types) {
      try {
        return type.serialize(value) //throws error if type can't serialize value
      }
      catch (e) { }
    }
    throw new Error('No type matched')
  }
}
```

Let me know if you need me to explain any of that.  Hope it helps. Good luck!

---

#### Update 1

@csander [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725972/typescript-type-annotation-to-express-variable-numbers-of-generics#comment78410106_45726251):

> Thanks for the answer! This was my original solution. The problem I have though is that not all the types I pass in will necessarily be `Serializer<T>` with the same `T`. For example, I might have a `Serializer<string>` and a `Serializer<number>`, so the desired `T` for the union would be `string | number` but neither of the original `Serializer`s implement `Serializer<string | number>`. Does that make sense?

That is an excellent point and I failed to address it.  The short answer is that in TypeScript [generic type parameters are covariant](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7933), meaning that, in fact, you can always narrow a `Serializer<string|number>` value to one of type `Serializer<string>`:

```
declare const numberOrStringSerializer: Serializer<number | string>;
const justStringSerializer: Serializer<string> = numberOrStringSerializer;
const justNumberSerializer: Serializer<number> = numberOrStringSerializer;
```

(This type of narrowing is unsound in general, but TypeScript does it for reasons of performance and developer convenience.  There are [possible fixes for it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10717) but they're not part of the language yet.)

That being said, type inference on the `UnionSerializer` constructor will [not automatically infer the union type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905523/why-isnt-the-type-argument-inferred-as-a-union-type):

```
new UnionSerializer([justNumberSerializer, justStringSerializer]); // error
```

You can manually specify it, however:

```
new UnionSerializer<string|number>([justNumberSerializer, justStringSerializer]); // ok
```

This is a bit annoying, but it works.  There *may* be ways to improve this experience but I'm not sure at the moment.  Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was my original solution. The problem I have though is that not all the types I pass in will necessarily be `Serializer<T>` with the same `T`. For example, I might have a `Serializer<string>` and a `Serializer<number>`, so the desired `T` for the union would be `string | number` but neither of the original `Serializer`s implement `Serializer<string | number>`. Does that make sense?