# Inferred type in generic functions with strictNullChecks

Tags: typescript

With typescript 2.5.2 the following code fails to compile with `strictNullChecks`:

```
function ifnull<T>(x: T | null | undefined, def: T): T
{
    return x != null ? x : def;
}

console.log(ifnull(2, 1));
```

giving the error:

```
Argument of type '2' is not assignable to parameter of type '1 | null | undefined'.
```

It seems it infers T to be `1` instead of number. When you compile without strictNullChecks it correctly infers the type `number`. I am not confident enough to know if this is a bug in Typescript or expected behaviour, so I prefer to ask here before I fill a bug report.

Is this expected? what's the rationale of the strict inference, and is there a way to define `ifnull` without having to call it as `ifnull<number>(...)` or `ifnull<string>(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

The rationale for the strict inference is probably best explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905723/2887218) by one of TypeScript's core contributors, @RyanCavanaugh. Most of the time you don't want TypeScript to accept two different types for the same type parameter by inferring their union.  I don't know why the behavior is different with `strictNullChecks` turned off, though.

One thing you can do to fix it is to [delay](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) the inference of the second parameter, by using `& {}` like this:

```
function ifnull<T>(x: T | null | undefined, def: T & {}): T
{
    return x != null ? x : def;
}

console.log(ifnull(2, 1)); // okay
```

Hope that helps; good luck!