# Avoid implicit `any` when using Object.values with union of Records

Tags: typescript, type-safety

Why does the code below silently assumes `fooValues` is `any`. And is it possible to avoid this implicit `any`. I tried the "noImplicitAny" tsconfig option, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
type Record1 = Record<string,  { a: 1 }>
type Record2 = Record<string,  { b: 1 }>
const foo: Record1 | Record2 = {}
const bar: Record1 = {}
// Why is `fooValues` any[]???
const fooValues = Object.values(foo)
// This one is OK.
const barValues = Object.values(bar)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwIxQLywS1APAM7DICWAdgOYA0UUA3lAIYBcUmAvgHwBQokXEjQAmbEPzFSlWvSYAjdlz68kFElABmiROzjCMUAD4TR4hp1WJ1wKPObI9eNJhwXevAPSeoAdQAWIFBkRFAABtqIAGrMADYArhBEYSwUIADaALoA-LlWNlo6MQlJ4gDy8gBWCMAAdABucYlEABSRAJQe3lAAKv4hUNbQA2UA0rX5GvbIxc3lVTUNTUkt051AA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an issue about implicit `any`.  The `any` you're seeing here is actually quite explicit, and has to do with the [standard library's call signatures for `Object.values()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/06a2210eb53cfce968dc855fcc13738d95d4556a/lib/lib.es2017.object.d.ts#L26-L32):

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): T[];
  values(o: {}): any[];
}
```

That's an [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) function with two call signatures.  The first is a generic function that requires a parameter with an index-signature and returns a strongly-typed array; the second is a non-generic function that takes any non-nullish parameter and returns `any[]`.  When you call `Object.values()`, the compiler has to choose which call signature to apply by trying each one in turn.   Apparently when you call `Object.values(bar)` it chooses the first signature, but when you call `Object.values(foo)` it chooses the second.

---

Let's investigate what's happening by breaking each call signature into its own separate function:

```
const objectValues1: <T>(o: { [s: string]: T; } | ArrayLike<T>) => T[] = Object.values;
const objectValues2: (o: {}) => any[] = Object.values;
```

Here, `objectValues1` only has the generic signature and `objectValues2` has only the non-generic one.  Let's look at `bar`:

```
const barVals1 = objectValues1(bar); // okay {a: 1}[]
// T is inferred as {a: 1}
```

Great, `objectValues1()` works; `T` is inferred as `{a: 1}` and you get a strongly-typed output.  Now let's try `foo`:

```
const fooVals1 = objectValues1(foo); // error!
// T inferred as {a: 1}, but
/* Argument of type 'Record<string, { a: 1; }> | Record<string, { b: 1; }>' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<{ a: 1; }> | { [s: string]: { a: 1; }; }'. */

const fooVals2 = objectValues2(foo); // any[]
```

Oops, that didn't work and we had to try `objectValues2()` which produces `any`.  But why didn't it work?

---

If you look, the compiler just infers `T` as `{a: 1}` instead of as the union `{a: 1} | {b: 1}`.  Generic type parameter inference is an art, not a science.  Well, for humans, anyway.  For the compiler, type parameter inference operates by some heuristics that the language designers came up with.  These heuristics will often reject a call that requires synthesizing a union type not present in any of the inference sites.  Why?  Because it turns out that this ends up accepting things which weren't intended. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905523/why-isnt-the-type-argument-inferred-as-a-union-type/39905723#39905723) for more info.  The type of `foo` presents  both `{a: 1}` and `{b: 1}` as possible candidates for `T`, but since neither choice works, the inference fails, and the compiler proceeds to the second call signature.

---

So, what can you do?  Well, the easiest thing is to just manually specify the generic type parameter as the union.  The compiler won't infer it for you, but it will accept it if you specify it:

```
const fooValues = Object.values<{ a: 1 } | { b: 1 }>(foo);
// Array<{a: 1} | {b: 1}>
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDGB7ATgEwIxQLywS1APAM7DICWAdgOYA0UA3lAIYBcUmAvgHwBQokuJGgBM2QfmKlKtBlABGbTrx5IKJKADNEiNnCEYoAH3Eix9DisRrg8psl140mHOZ48A9O9XqtiAGpMADYArhBEYgDycgBWCMAAdABuQaFEABS+zOF6EiTk1HSMrOxQHEayCiXcAJSW1rbIASFhkTFxSSlhaXJ2tXXqiQ76kvkyRYql5YyVSmK+ANxubt42iG3wwE2p6GwEACpcaTqyANpEbHnSALpse-OTxgCCyMhMIAAyZADWEPtc1dguFA9icrq1YhsOs0iIsVlA1hDNp0iMI2Ec2OYAVggUwKCBQeD2sloYt+jYeo0gkRnPD1kjoehur17p54V83gxiugOKCPO5gVAyOFKBoIC8IKgspzFBYyZptE1qWIEXEtmFGb5qiz+WLkCgAIR8gUi3USqX0LkcOhyYLADwAKigzyowQAthAKKsNFB+NAAOQ5NAjaSFZiKe7ccqBwiXAoVcOlLh+qA8IVQCiIGxMIhEMhUChMOSBaDARBQMB2Jju4Bi+He31QP3PV4fb6-cbsCNA4yMM4XKTUG6yLkRiN++JQe3uZZWHwKqmiHAqjZqlEZbRaqCs3H4q4z+q+VeEyHE1IEDucKbyCbcdeILVG5tvc+WqYzbhAA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it all makes sense. That being said, it raises a very big concern regarding relying on TS's type-safety heavily. The built-in typing for `Object.values` is failing you without you knowing it and, it appears, there is nothing you can do about such "concealed" `any` popping up in your codebase and potentially tainting a significant part of it. Is there anything one can do about it?

Comment: Hmm, relying "heavily" on TS's type safety is probably a bad idea just because TS has a lot of intentional [unsoundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) where incorrect code is allowed so as not to make correct code prohibitively annoying to write.  To try to avoid all uses of `any` in particular you could try a linter rule like eslint's [`no-explicit-any`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md)