# typescript union types from spread operator

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have a function with the following signature:

```js
test<T>(...args: T[]): T
```

if I call the function like this:

```js
const a = test(1, 2, 3)
```

everything works as expected (and `a` is of type `number`), but if I call it that way:

```js
const a = test(1, 2, "asd")
```

I get any error:
[EDIT] The 2 is red underlined: `Argument of type '2' is not assignable to parameter of type '1'.`, witch might be a bit misleading because the arguments are constants, but if I call it that way:

```js
let arg1 = 1;
let arg2 = "asd";
const a = test(arg1, arg2);
```

I get the error: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.`

How can I make it so that the function would (in the second case) has a return type of `number | string` **without explicitly specifying it in the generic parameter.**

Comment: What does "I get any error" mean?  Assuming you mean "an error", please consider editing the post to include the text of this error and where it occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is intentional that `T` is not inferred as a union; see [Why isn't the type argument inferred as a union type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905523/why-isnt-the-type-argument-inferred-as-a-union-type/39905723#39905723), as well as [microsoft/TypeScript#19596](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19596) and [microsoft/TypeScript#26746](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26746) for reasons why.

Probably the easiest way around this is to allow `args` to be any array type `T` whatsoever, and then get its element type by [indexing into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with the key type `number`:

```
declare function test<T extends any[]>(...args: T): T[number];
const a = test(1, 2, 3) // number
const b = test(1, 2, "asd") // number | string
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwxAGcMAeAFXhAA9DVgj4pUBPAbQF0A+ACgDoBsAOZEAXPHIBKceTapkAWwBGIGBwDcAKDB4STeAF4CxDDwCMAGngAmKwGZJ8APRP485au26M8JYeMk5la28ABEUETAoY4ubooqMPAAPvAkMFioQppAA)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the call signature you are looking for:

```js
<T extends Array<unknown>>(...args: T): T[number]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0YF4YDMCuZhQJbhgB4AVGeADwTABMIYBBAJ0YEMBPQrAazBAHcwAPkEAKAHQSWjAOYQAXDGIBKBcQDaYDAFsARvEYBdGAG9G8KBkZgYU2WoAMBgL4BuAFAfQkWCxRxEUCIAjAA0MABMYQBELBDUUUpuQA)