# Narrow number argument of function to be literal type

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a method that takes a `id:number` and an partial object that must contain `id`, with the SAME value as the 1st argument.

here's what I'm thinking

```
type MyData = {id: number}

function update<K extends MyData['id']>(id: K, newValues: Partial<MyData> & {id: K}): MyData {
    throw 'not implemented'
}

// expected failure?
update(3, {id: 4})
```

what's weird is the intellisense seems to agree with my logic but it's not enforced
[image: intellisense suggesting type Partial & {id: 3}]

if I extract that type in the intellisense suggestion, and try to use it, I do get the failure I expected when calling the function

```
type ArgType = Partial<MyData> & {id: 3}
const argProof: ArgType = {id: 4}
```

[image: error message on id property]

how should I write my function to get the proper narrowing I'm looking for?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBDYioF4oG8CWATAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOAvgFD0BmJRAxsNgPZFQli5kEADwBpKBAAewCEVwBnWAmSIA2gHI86gLoA%20ABR5CogDTEIAdwBqiADYkI8wgAVE1TneFwkKXVABkWEZQorQAlITeKlj0UHFQwAAW1FwWUOpEXMBQ2GRgthBksjK46vQM9AD0lRKSkBwQuFBMiNj21BAA-PT8gjL6AMxmOARQACzhjPSgkFAAgtQA5gAq4NAYru7YnlG%20AUGjAwxsPPLZbovOKVxMhAsra%20gHhBNAA)

Comment: Are you asking "what's going on" and want an explanation?  Or are you wanting a fix?  They are different questions and I want to know whether I should bother digging into *why* the compiler infers a union for `K` as opposed to just *fixing* it by lowering the inference priority of your second `K` appearance, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1pgkW).  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: great point @jcalz, I'm was indeed looking for "how to fix", thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intent was that when you call `update()`, the compiler should *infer* the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter from the argument passed as the `id` parameter, and then *check* the value passed in as the `newValues` parameter against it.  But the compiler had other plans; it decided to infer the type parameter from *both locations*, and synthesized a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
update(3, { id: 4 });
// function update<3 | 4>(id: 3 | 4, newValues: Partial<MyData> & { id: 3 | 4; }): MyData
```

That's not *wrong*, per se; one could imagine someone else wanting exactly this behavior for a function of the same call signature.  (Frankly I'm a little surprised that this happened, since the common complaint I see is the opposite, where people *want* a union but the compiler refuses; see [Why isn't the type argument inferred as a union type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905523/why-isnt-the-type-argument-inferred-as-a-union-type).  But I'm not going to focus on figuring out why.)  It's not what you want, though.

---

Again, your intent was that the appearance of the type parameter inside `newValues` was just for *checking* and not for *inference*.  There is a request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) for such "non-inferential type parameter usage", where you'd mark the type parameter `T` with `NoInfer<T>` and it would block inference while leaving everything else alone.  Like this:

```
function update<T extends MyData['id']>(
  id: T,
  newValues: Partial<MyData> & { id: NoInfer<T> }
): MyData {
  throw 'not implemented'
}
```

Now, there's no *direct* support for this.  But the GitHub issue does mention several ways of emulating this behavior.  One such approach is to "lower the priority" of the inference site by intersecting it with `{}` (which doesn't do anything to non-nullable types):

```
type NoInfer<T> = T & {};
```

If you do this then things behave as you desire:

```
update(3, { id: 4 }); // error! 4 is not assignable to 3
update(3, { id: 3 }); // okay
```

There are other approaches mentioned in there, like adding another generic type parameter [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the first:

```
function update<T extends MyData['id'], U extends T>(
  id: T,
  newValues: Partial<MyData> & { id: U }
): MyData {
  throw 'not implemented'
}

update(3, { id: 4 }); // error! 4 is not assignable to 3
update(3, { id: 3 }); // okay
```

The different approaches have their pros and cons.  For more information you should consult the issue in GitHub.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAiBDYioF4oG8oEsAmAXFAHYCuAtgEYQBOUAvgLABQxi5EAzmIgMbQB5APZhOWFiyhQAZqWK9gOIcSikweZBAA8AFSgQAHsAjE8YuEhQBtAOT4bAXQB8ACklTchKDoA07qcQQAO4AaogANqRcRAAKiDSKEVoWyIhOUABkWJ5EekzMUgCURCko4gUewAAWNEJBUDbEQsC45GDhEBzExng27vnuAPSD+gaQChB4Mog4kTQQAPzuahrGLgDMPtn4RAAsDIUA3EMjsvKKyqrqmlrrUAA+ULuuO1B3j7tbgaERUZyx8US4WSCFS6Sy2Fe7yehwOJVBKBYA1Y7C4PH4UAAMnVaDEaEp8aByu5QJAoAA5IQASWI0lounSGD0EPox2Y7jOCiUKhWNz0hmMpnMCMQtnszjcFSkr18-hIwTCkWiUDiCRwSVKaUy2y8lJpdJoDIY7mKsBF5Q8UGqtXqjWarXanRMPT6FWRUl5a02Or2B1hw30NFqNAAhE9cGImi1EJxODgAOZsSgdK1CN7La5eraQrx3ehHKABoQAa0QIAkzGRbA43D40B0QSEAHETLQcLwxJgOXIuZdPdp+UYTGYzZZRXZeg4tgBVUaCkc6VxymV+KXyn5K-4qwHq4Ga8E+qCz-JFeFji2VGp1BpRh0dLou-oVj2ZiAbbM5cP5-0jWjBsP7Dgkb2jGcaJogybQMAabrBmqxvt6OZEHmBZFqW5bspWQA)