# How do I create a literal type for React component parameters?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created the SelectProps interface!

```
export interface SelectProps {
  value: string
  options: string[]
  onChange: (value: any) => void
}
```

I created react component!

```
<Select
  value="red"
  options={['dark', 'white']}
  onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
/>
```

How do I make value one of the values of options ('dark' | 'white') ? That is, I want to get this type:

```
type Value = 'dark' | 'white'
```

I must say right away this solution is not suitable:

```
const options = ['dark', 'white'] as const
type Value = typeof options[number]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to do it:

```
export interface SelectProps<O extends string> {
  value: O & {}
  options: O[]
  onChange: (value: O) => void
}

const Select = <O extends string>(props: SelectProps<O>) => <div></div>
```

As the others have said, `SelectProps` needs to be generic. We use `O` as an array for `options` and as the type for `value`. Important here are two things:

First, the intersection with an empty object `{}` for the `value` field. This signals to TypeScript that the `value` field shall not be used for inference of `O`.

Secondly, we constrain `O` to be a `string`. This lets TypeScript infer the string  literal types `'dark' | 'white'` instead of just `string`.

```
function main() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                value="red" // Error: Type '"red"' is not assignable to type '"dark" | "white"'
                options={['dark', 'white']}
                onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            />
            <Select
                value="dark"
                options={['dark', 'white']}
                onChange={(value) => console.log(value)}
            />
        </div>
    )  
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQCUCmBDAxsgZnGCJAIjkx2NFDQA9ZEkwA7BNOXbNJAZTQBs0OAAoEoAZwA8AeSS1WTACZikYhHGYBzAHxIA3qCRIAbhj4BXNAC4kMgGR6AvgaQwoCMDCZjrUgNoBdZ08AYQALDCYNKyQAChNzaKkASiQAXh0jGDAFUCcQUCxPVR5+QWRUpGlZGnklFTVNLRioUW8SgWFW6S0U9MqFMCMtCQB6AaGqEFwzJhwPJiQIDGYYlP0QQ0MyBDM4BZjnTc2Jca1Do4uJXg6Ec4v741MLVNI0BWIkEZGkAFE4Ajg1gAKgBPKBcADkr3eEMYyiYMGQGDEYjAGiYGAARgIkAgYLiwZDiAoMHAANYfAA+JAA7qEwKxiBC7g8jq53EVUrpfBCSeSIQAaJAQukMtAQ-x5VmskLhSJoLlxJ5oXo6QpeGACAB0fBgGiVCSSUulhhGZw2Jsq1zKLJN8WexNJFNt0vZ8zEXJ5fLJguFotYEuNls2soiUUV9pVaTVRU1aB1eoNFiNLqOZpdo1O5xSSFyoCAA)

Comment: Nice trick with `O & {}`! Learned smth new! I will include it in my blog, if you don't mind

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine nice to hear :D you can add it for sure - here are some sources: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731 & https://stackoverflow.com/a/73733110/8613630

Comment: @TobiasS. I would say the `& {}` reduces the priority of that site in inference. It will infer from it if there is nothing else to infer from.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQCUCmBDAxsgZnGCJAIjkx2NFDQA9ZEkwA7BNOXbNJAZTQBs0OAAoEoAZwA8AeSS1WTACZikYhHGYBzAHxIA3qCRIAbhj4BXNAC4kMgGR6AvgaQwoCMDCZiA-NakBtAF1nTwBhAAsMJg0rJAAKE3NYqQBKJABeHSMYMAVQJxBQLE9VHn5BZHSkaVkaeSUVNU0tOKhRMWteAWF26S00zOqFMCMtCQB6YdGqEFwzJhwPJiQIDGY4tP0QQ0MyBDM4ZbjnHZ2JKa0T0+uJLoqr68fjUwt00jQFYiRx8ZIyT4eT1OYUi0TQ6V0CReaAGOmKXhgAgAdHwYBooUkUgUgadxpdtk8JhcrmkkPlQEA

Comment: @TobiasS. https://catchts.com/undocumented-features#inference

Answer (score 1):

You need to use typescript Generics:

```
export interface SelectProps<Value> {
  value: Value
  options: Value[]
  onChange: (value: Value) => void
}
```

But you also need to change `Select` component, so it also takes a `type parameter`, and passes it to `SelectProps` interface:

```
    function Select<Value>(props:SelectProps<Value>){
                            ...
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Erfan! But how do I create a literal type? Following your example, I will only get the string type! And I need the value to be a literal type, let's say ('1', '2', '3')!

Comment: @Nikita From a personal experience: I have been where you are currently a lot writing react/typescript, I never found any solution other than creating a literal type of all possible values manually.

Comment: thanks for the answer! Thanks to you, we managed to come up with such a solution! Perhaps it will be useful to you! - [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-morning-r32d3n?file=/src/Select.tsx)