# Typescript: Ensure all properties use the same tuple type

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics, type-safety

I've got a function with a generic that is a tuple of 1 or a tuple of 2 elements.
I want to ensure that all properties used in the function use the same length tuple.

```js
type TypeA = [string] // Tuple of 1 element
type TypeB = [string, string] // Tuple of 2 elements
type Header = TypeA | TypeB

interface SomeObject<H extends Header> {
    prop1: H
    prop2: H
}

function useHeader<H extends Header>(someObject:SomeObject<H>) {
    // do something
}

useHeader({
    prop1: ["tuple of 1 element"],
    prop2: [
        "tuple of", 
        "2 elements"
    ] // <-- I want an error here, because prop1 and prop2 use diffrent tuples
})
```

I noticed that when I change `TypeA` to `number` and `TypeB` to `string`, then Typescript gives an error when I mix numbers and strings.
Is it possible to make Typescript generate an error when tuples of different length are used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this approach:

```js
type TypeA = [string] // Tuple of 1 element
type TypeB = [string, string] // Tuple of 2 elements

type Header = TypeA | TypeB

interface SomeObject<H extends Header> {
    prop1: H
    prop2: H & {} // <------- CHANGE IS HERE
}

function useHeader<H extends Header>(someObject: SomeObject<H>) {
    // do something
}

useHeader({
    prop1: ["tuple of 1 element"],
    prop2: [
        "tuple of",
        "2 elements"
    ] // <-- I want an error here, because prop1 and prop2 use diffrent tuples
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYRPzw)

This line `H & {}` means "make inference priority lower". In other words, TS will infer first `H` for `prop1` and only then second `prop2` and not simultaneously.

While this is not documented feature, Ryan Cavanaugh (development lead of the TypeScript team) says [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731) that it's *"...by design..."* (w/emphasis) and *"...probably going to work for the foreseeable future."*

More undocumented features you can find in [my blog](https://catchts.com/undocumented-features). This particular hack was provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74093078/how-do-i-create-a-literal-type-for-react-component-parameters#74093982)

---

WIhout undocumented tricks:

```js
type TypeA = [string] // Tuple of 1 element
type TypeB = [string, string] // Tuple of 2 elements

type Header = TypeA | TypeB
type IsLengthEqual<T extends any[], U extends any[]> = U extends { length: T['length'] } ? U : never

interface SomeObject<H extends Header, H2 extends Header> {
    prop1: H
    prop2: IsLengthEqual<H, H2>
}

function useHeader<H extends Header, H2 extends Header>(someObject: SomeObject<H, H2>) {
    // do something
}

useHeader({
    prop1: ["tuple of 1 element"],
    prop2: [
        "tuple of",
        'dfg'
    ] // error
})
```

---

And with only one generic

```js
type TypeA = [string] // Tuple of 1 element
type TypeB = [string, string] // Tuple of 2 elements

type Header = TypeA | TypeB

interface SomeObject<H extends Header> {
    prop1: H
    prop2: { [Prop in keyof H]: string }
}

function useHeader<H extends Header>(someObject: SomeObject<[...H]>) {
    // do something
}

useHeader({
    prop1: ["tuple of 1 element"],
    prop2: [
        "tuple of",
        'dfg'
    ] // error
})
```

Comment: that pretty cool, thanks! any idea why isn't it documented? is it experimental?

Comment: @HagaiKalinhoff not, it is not experimental, it is by design, see official [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point. I have added another approach, also it looks like this behaviour is by design, so don't think it will be removed/disabled in the future. See [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731)

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine - Hey, it doesn't get better than that!