# Why doesn't generic type inference infer a union from two sites?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

Consider

```
const pairer = <T,>(a: T, b:T) => ({a, b})
const mypair = pairer(3n, true)
```

This is an error in TypeScript 4.9, namely

> Argument of type boolean is not assignable to parameter of type bigint

So clearly TS has inferred T to be bigint in the call, making the call invalid. But there is a perfectly good type for T that makes the call legal, namely `bigint | boolean`:

```
const myotherpair = pairer<bigint | boolean>(3n, true)
```

compiles and runs fine.

Why doesn't TypeScript infer the type that makes the code it is processing valid? Is there a concise writeup of the inference of a generic parameter from an actual call with enough detail to understand why it chose `bigint` in the `mypair` call? (The [TypeScript handbook page on generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) doesn't cover cases with two uses of the parameter.) And perhaps most importantly, is there a way for me to define my generic so that the unadorned call mypair(x,y) will infer the type `(typeof x) | (typeof y)`?

Comment: "And perhaps most importantly, is there a way for me to define my generic so that the unadorned call mypair(x,y) will infer the type (typeof x) | (typeof y)?" There should only be one main question per post; is this the primary question (in which case the "why" question is not one) or do you want to move it to a new post?

Comment: The way to define this would be write `<T, U>(a: T, b: U): { a: T | U, b: T | U } => ({ a, b })` as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5OQ9W).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining how it works and why it's necessary to do this (assuming this was indeed your primary question).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes that's really the primary question, thanks, and indeed, that declaration works like a charm in this case. The syntax sort of obscures the semantics that we're really thinking of a and b as the same type, just a type big enough to contain them both, but as it does precisely what's desired, we can just comment it. So sure, an answer would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the following is the primary question:

> Is there a way for me to define my generic so that the unadorned call `mypair(x,y)` will infer the type `(typeof x) | (typeof y)`

As you saw, you can't do this with a single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T`.  The compiler does not like to synthesize [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) from multiple inference sites, as described in [Why isn't the type argument inferred as a union type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39905523/2887218).

If you want to emulate this behavior, you can provide multiple type parameters, and then synthesize their union yourself:

```
const pairer = <T, U>(a: T, b: U): { a: T | U, b: T | U } => ({ a, b });
```

In the above, `T` can be inferred only from `a`, and `U` can be inferred only from `b`.  They are independent.  The return type, on the other hand, is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) as `{ a: T | U, b: T | U }`, to provide the same output as you would get if both `a` and `b` were used to infer a single type argument.

Note that if you don't annotate the return type, the compiler will infer the more specific type `{a: T, b: U}`. Presumably you actually *prefer* the wider version where both `a` and `b` are of the same type, though.

You can see it in action:

```
const mypair = pairer(3n, true);
/* const mypair: {
    a: bigint | boolean;
    b: bigint | boolean;
} */
```

Looks good. There is no complaint at the call site, and the type of `mypair` has `bigint | boolean` members as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAIAOBDAlgJwKbvgXngDwAqANPAKoB8AFMgFzynwBGD5AlAwN7z2PwAfCmVb8h5eAF88leNR7IRU9mChx4AWwCeKDHiRos6agGZIZWOgCumdgG5gAegBU8CDATbd6bsHj-eBmZUAHNUSAQhZnBwABtMZEgHAJYg0PDIlhj4xIdpZ0cgA)

Answer (score 0):

To me this is fairly simple, it's the least surprising behaviour :

You'd expect the compiler to warn you when you pass 2 different types.
When can see that as a feature that you can bypass this warning by setting the type as a union.

This works as intended per [#37673](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37673), but you can always an open issue ([#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312)) asking for that particular feature to allow the inference to be widden by the parameters.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard for me to know what one means by "two different types" in TypeScript. There's just a type system, and it allows for abitrary meets and joins of types. The actual occurrence of this came up in the guts of a fairly complicated generic, and the actual types that were coming in as the two parameters were already overlapping unions of other types, so actually I found the asymmetry of the two argument positions more surprising than the compiler just combining the two into one big union. So I guess "surprising" is very context-dependent.

Comment: So I guess the important things are to _understand_ what TypeScript is really doing when it infers types, and to be able to _control_ it so that when I want to make something like this that will generate unions I can (if possible).

Comment: Btw I edited my answer. There is a year old issue asking for the same feature as you : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I am gathering from the issues that there is not currently a direct way to define a generic like this that automatically infers the union of its parameters. So I guess the last piece is a good reference on what TypeScript actually does, if such a thing exists.