# TypeScript: Union Is Cut By Generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

What should I do to make `wrapper` return `string | number` type? The point is that I need to have `extract` as a generic function to automatically recognize `getter`'s result type. Now `wrapper` is considered to return `string` only. Thank you in advance.

```js
function extract<M>(getter: () => M): M {
  return getter()
}

let getter: (() => string) | (() => number) 

function wrapper() {
  const result = extract(getter)
  //    ^                ^ it fails to match `string` with `number` here
  //    ^ I expect typeof result to be `string | number` but it is just `string` for some reason
  return result
}
```

Comment: TypeScript doesn't like to synthesize unions to join multiple inference candidates, because often this isn't what people want (e.g., given `function f<T>(x: T, y: T){}` most people expect `f(1, "two")` to be an error even though presumably `string | number` would work.)  If you want such a union you can manually specify the type argument when calling `extract()` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WYLbrm).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, explicitly specifying definitely works. However for me the background of this is still tricky. Could you please hint/point a documentation place that describes this as better as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript inference algorithm for [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments is effectively a set of heuristic rules which have been found to be useful in a wide range of real world code situations.  The type checker tries to match two types, one of which contains some utterances of a generic type parameter like `T`.  It is possible that this matching process generates *multiple* candidate type arguments.  For example, in the following function and call:

```
function f<T>(x: T, y: T) { }
f(a, b);
```

The compiler has two candidates for `T`... it could be `typeof a`, or `typeof b`.  When both types are the same, there's no issue:

```
f(1, 2); // okay, T inferred as number
f("one", "two"); // okay, T inferred as string
```

But what should the compiler do when the two candidates are *different*?

```
f(1, "two"); // what should happen here?
```

Here the compiler needs to do something with `string` and `number`.  One might imagine that the compiler could synthesize a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and infer that `T` is `string | number`.  But that's not what happens.

It turns out that, in real world code, most people think that the above call should be *rejected*.  The consensus is that `f(1, "two")` isn't a valid call because `1` and `"two"` are different types.  So the compiler tends not to synthesize unions; instead it picks one candidate (usually the "first" one) and then checks the others against it:

```
f(1, "two"); // T inferred as string, error!
//   ~~~~~ <-- Argument of type 'string' is not assignable 
// to parameter of type 'number'.
```

See [Why isn't the type argument inferred as a union type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39905523/2887218) for an answer by the TS Team development lead.

---

Unfortunately for your code, something very similar happens:

```
extract(getter); // error!
// function extract<string>(getter: () => string): string
```

The compiler needs to match the type `() => M` against `(() => string) | (() => number))`.  This generates two candidates for `M`: `string` and `number`.  Because the compiler prefers not to synthesize unions in cases like this, it chooses `string` and checks against that, causing the error.

So that's why it's happening.

---

There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#44312](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44312) asking for some way to annotate the type parameter so that the compiler will infer unions where necessary to prevent errors.  Perhaps that would look like

```
// Not valid TS, don't do this:
declare function f<allowunion T>(x: T, y: T): void;
declare function extract<allowunion M>(getter: () => M): M;
```

but for now there is no such feature.

---

The easiest workaround here would be to give up on type argument *inference* and just specify the type argument yourself, manually.  If you want `M` or `T` to be `string | number`, just tell the compiler that:

```
f<string | number>(1, "two"); // okay
const result = extract<string | number>(getter); // okay
// const result: string | number;
```

There are doubtless other ways to change the call signature so that inference succeeds, but then your call signature will be more complicated and you'd need to compute your original `M` type from it (e.g., the [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75636320/2887218) using `ReturnType<T>`).  It depends on your use cases whether you'd prefer to do something like that instead.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.9.5#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)

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue is that you are telling TypeScript that the getter is a function that returns a string, or a function that returns a number. You could do it like this:

```
function extract<M>(getter: () => M): M {
  return getter()
}

let getter: () => string | number

function wrapper() {
  const result = extract(getter)
  return result
}
```

That works for me

Comment: Thank you. And what is the deep mechanics hidden there? Why does it work that way?

Comment: I didn't know the internal reason, but I see a very good detailed explanation by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75638312/12180422) below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `M` to infer the return type of the function, try to infer the entire type of the function first, then use `ReturnType` as the return type:

```
function extract<F extends () => unknown>(getter: F): ReturnType<F> {
  return getter() as ReturnType<F>;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5QE4ENoB4BiK6yYAJgM6IAUAlIgLwB8i4A1mHAO5iNUDmyKFGQYAXInw1xAJUEgMYACoBPAA7ICzAN4BYAFCJEGOQsQChI2oiyVZUeUrUb8jANz6Avvv0AbQWcFhMWorJkRyTBgwPjoAHxC6MLAQAFsAIxE6bz1QSFgERE5sVXUMK10DRAgECKNkchAfKAYiTBwofkDM90qAel7DQwA9AH5sw2N7U2MGps8gA)

Comment: Thank you. Is not this an anti-pattern since [the doc says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#push-type-parameters-down) to push the type down?